# Javascript: Copy an image into a variable to place somewhere?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Can I use javascript to take a hidden image on a page, define it as a variable and then later place somewhere else on the page?

So far, I figure that I might be able to do this like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="images" class="images hidden">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats/" style="">
</div>


<div onclick="createImgHtml">
  <button>Click to show image</button>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var images = document.getElementById('images');

function createImgHtml() {
  return '<div>' + images + '</div>';
}
```

Obviously, this won't work as of right now, because I don't know how to write the HTML for the `<div>` containing the image. How do I have to change my function so that it actually creates HTML code using the variable and also places it on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you store/use the image.

1. Same scope.

You have already save the dom in a variable, why create html??

2. Other

You stringify the dom object first, then save wherever.

Below is the code for same runtime scope, just clone your dom as many as you like, append it to document.

```js
var images = document.getElementById('images')
images2 = images.cloneNode()
images2.className = "images"
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]

function createImgHtml() {
  body.appendChild(images2.cloneNode().appendChild(img.cloneNode()))
  // return '<div>' + images + '</div>';
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="images" class="images hidden">
  <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=Hello" style="">
</div>


<div>
  <button onclick="createImgHtml()">Click to show image</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the id to the `img`.

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://example.com/blah.jpg" id="images" />
```

**JS**

```
const images = document.querySelector('#images')
const imageSrc = images.getAttribute('src');

function createImageHtml() {
  return `<div>${imageSrc}</div>`;
}
```

Links:

[Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

[Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

[Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you fully but here are maybe some answers that could help

- You can add a class to all the images you want to hide and than use javascript to get that by classname and loop through it.
- Why not use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store an array of images

You can loop through it or even have the objects

You can print to the screen using javasript read more about it here.

[HTML DOM appendChild() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you do not need to move the image but instead, show it (*make it unhidden*).

That can be easily done by removing the class `hidden` from the containing `div`:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="images" class="images hidden">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats/" style="">
</div>


<div>
  <button onclick="showImage">Click to show image</button>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function showImage() {
  var images = document.getElementById('images');
  images.className = images.className.replace('hidden',' ');
}
```

P.S.: I moved the `onclick` attribute to the `button` instead of the `div`.

```js
function showImage() {
  var images = document.getElementById('images');
  images.className = images.className.replace('hidden',' ');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  dispaly: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="images" class="images hidden">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats/" style="">
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="showImage">Click to show image</button>
</div>
```